# How to not require extended user model fields for a superuser

Tags: django, django-models

I have extended the in built user model in django via `AbstractUser`.  However when it cam to deployment and to create a superuser it failed because of having a null entry in some of the additional fields in the extended model.  Is there a way to have these fields not required for a superuser but required for a normal user.  (I presume this is a typical use case - as I don't need an admin to fill out address, account number etc...)

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):  
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    phone_number = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    account_number = models.IntegerField()


    house_name_number = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="house name or number")
    street_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    town_city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    county = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using mandatory fields in models, you have to set them to optional using `null=True, blank=True` and let the validation happen in [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/). `For users other than admin create a form that checks for extra fields and`[validate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/) `those fields`. Render this form through templates at the time of signup/registration. Also instead of using modelforms `use forms.Form` this will give you a better level of customization. This will make extra fields mandatory for all users other than Admin.